# App could not authenticate with Facebook and Firebase after conversion to swift 3 syntax

Tags: ios, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, swift3

I've cleaned out my project to iron out all the errors. App seems to launch and the login page seems to work, but when I tried logging in to Facebook, this is what happens:

```
TCP_CONNECTION_EVENT_TLS_HANDSHAKE_COMPLETE in response to state ready and error (null)  
2016-09-15 12:36:50.254067 2[3083:89230] [] tcp_connection_event_notify 12 event: TCP_CONNECTION_EVENT_TLS_HANDSHAKE_COMPLETE, reason: nw_connection event, should deliver: true  
2016-09-15 12:36:50.254511 2[3083:89230] [] tcp_connection_get_statistics DNS: 3ms/7ms since start, TCP: 61ms/76ms since start, TLS: 99ms/172ms since start  
2016-09-15 12:36:50.492341 2[3083:89140] [] tcp_connection_cancel 12  
2016-09-15 12:36:50.493012 2[3083:88773] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event Event mask: 0x4  
2016-09-15 12:36:50.493506 2[3083:88773] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event Socket received WRITE_CLOSE event  
2016-09-15 12:36:50.494087 2[3083:88773] [] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [12 graph.facebook.com:443 ready resolver (satisfied)]  
2016-09-15 12:36:50.494691 2[3083:88773] [] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [12.1 31.13.78.13:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)]  
2016-09-15 12:36:50.495482 2[3083:88773] [] __nw_socket_service_writes_block_invoke sendmsg(fd 15, 31 bytes): socket has been closed  
2016-09-15 12:36:50.495878 2[3083:88773] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_error [12.1 31.13.78.13:443 cancelled socket-flow (null)] Socket protocol sent error: [32] Broken pipe  
2016-09-15 12:36:50.496536 2[3083:88773] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_disconnected [12.1 31.13.78.13:443 cancelled socket-flow (null)] Output protocol disconnected  
2016-09-15 12:36:50.496888 2[3083:88773] [] nw_resolver_cancel_on_queue 0x6000003042f0  
2016-09-15 12:36:50.497285 2[3083:88773] [] -[NWConcrete_tcp_connection dealloc] 12
```

This is just a snippet of the log file of the output when I tried logging in.

By the way, my code is set up as such for the loginviewcontroller

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class FacebookLoginViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate{

    var loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.loginButton.center = self.view.center
        self.loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        self.view!.addSubview(loginButton)
        self.loginButton.delegate = self


        FIRAuth.auth()?.addAuthStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
            if let user = user {
                // User is signed in.
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loggedIn", sender: self)

            }
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
        print("user logged in")



        if(error != nil)
        {
        }

        else if(result.isCancelled){

        }

        else{
        // Exchange facebook credential for a firebase credential

        let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)

        // Login to firebase
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loggedIn", sender: self)
            print("user logged in to firebase")
            }
        }

    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("user logged out")
    }

}
```

here's the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        FIRApp.configure()
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let navAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
        let tabAppearance = UITabBar.appearance()

        let backImage = UIImage(named: "back")
        navAppearance.backIndicatorImage = backImage
        navAppearance.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage


        let lightBlackColour = UIColor(red: 50/255.0, green: 50/255.0, blue: 54/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        let lightYellowColour = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 250/255.0, blue: 36/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        navAppearance.tintColor = lightYellowColour
        navAppearance.barTintColor = lightBlackColour // Set the bar tint colour
        navAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: lightYellowColour]

        tabAppearance.barTintColor = lightBlackColour
        tabAppearance.tintColor = lightYellowColour

        let barButtonAppearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
        barButtonAppearance.setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -60), forBarMetrics: .Default)
        barButtonAppearance.setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -60), forBarMetrics: .Compact)

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent

        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Xcode 8.0 (GM and shipped version) has a logging bug, which you see above. I came across this tweet this morning that may help you: https://mobile.twitter.com/rustyshelf/status/775505191160328194. Set `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable` in the debug scheme. It won't get rid of everything, but it will go a long way.

Comment: Oh it isn't just the logging. I've recently worked on a project involving Facebook SDK and firebase SDK. In the code I've written above. Its supposed to allow a user to sign in via Facebook and create a user entry in firebase. But now there seems to be restricted connection to facebook and firebase database. But still thanks for the heads up, I'll go disable OS activity mode.

Comment: What does your app delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` look like?

Comment: Just updated the question above

Comment: Looks fine. I was having similar problems. I ended up switching to `FBSDKLoginButton` and observing `FBSDKAccessTokenDidChange` because the completion handler wasn't being called. Short term fix.

Comment: Aite, thanks for the hot fix. I'll try it out. For now I think I still prefer to stick to xcode 7 though. At least until the new swift is stabilised

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In My app also Facebook and Google Login not working in iOS 10. So I have made ON keychain sharing and it works. Like

[image: Scrrenshot]

It may help. Tell me if not.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks a lot for sharing @Max Now I really wonder how you figured that!

Comment: @SebastianSastre I figured out from error description of Facebook login block.

Answer (score 3):

Setting OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable 
in your debug scheme.

Answer (score 2):

Edit Scheme -> Run -> Arguments -> Environment Variables -> OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable