# Login with facebook not working ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-login

I know there are a number of answers solving this issue but none of them worked for me.

I have done the following things.

In `AppDelegate.m`
-`didFinishLaunching` method

```
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

-`openURL` method

```
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
```

-`applicationDidBecomeActive`

```
[FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
```

In `ViewController` -

```
FBSDKLoginButton *fbLoginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
fbLoginButton.center = self.view.center;
fbLoginButton.readPermissions =  @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
[self.view addSubview:fbLoginButton];
```

But when I go for facebook login, and i click OK. It shows a progress bar and then disappears. It doesn't come back to the ViewController.

After I click on 'Done', it goes back to the ViewController but it still displays 'Log in with Facebook' instead of 'Log out'.

It was working before. But now it does not.

[image: Here is the image of info.plist]

Comment: `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}` have you added this code? and all the things in plist as mentioned here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/

Comment: `plist` values like `URL types`, `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` etc

Comment: I forgot to mention it here but I have done that too @Mr.UB .

Comment: Are you using simulator or device?

Comment: @Mr.UB device with latest iOS

Comment: Remove the USB wire and try logging in again

Comment: @Mr.UB removing USB didn't work.

Comment: #imort FBSDKLogin works ?

Comment: @Suhaib yes import works. Even the login button shows up. But when we click on OK while login , it fails there.

Comment: if device have ios 10 then enable keychain sharing. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39568942/3463712

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. I guess this was iOS 9.3 specific issue.

I had to change `openUrl` method code in AppDelegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString*, id> *)options {
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app
                                                      openURL:url
                                            sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                   annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
```

}

I changed to this and it worked. Hope it helps someone else.