# Facebook Login is not working in ios10 and xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**it was working well in xcode 7.3.1 and ios 9.3 but after updating xcode it stoped working**

here is code which i have used

```
-(IBAction)ClickFacebook:(id)sender
{
 FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login
     logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile",@"email"]
     fromViewController:self
     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
    {
         if (error)
         {
             //NSLog(@"Process error");

             FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
             [loginManager logOut];
             [FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];

         }
         else if (result.isCancelled)
         {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");


         }
         else
         {
             FBSDKGraphRequest *requestFB = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                             initWithGraphPath:@"/me"
                                             parameters:@{ @"fields": @"name,email"}
                                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
             [requestFB startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection  *connection, id result,NSError  *error)
              {
                 //NSLog(@"%@",result);

              NSString *   strName=[result valueForKey:@"name"];

              NSString *   strEmail=[result valueForKey:@"email"];

                // [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:strEmail forKey:@"EMAIL"];
                // [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:1 forKey:@"Logged_in"];
                // [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:strName forKey:@"NAME"];

                 UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                 SignupJob *viewController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"signupjob"];
                 viewController.strEmail=strEmail;
                 viewController.strName =strName;
                 [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
             }];
         }
     }];
}
```

but after login in facebook it will not return back to native app and when i have debugged code it falls in

```
else if (result.isCancelled)
         {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");


         }
```

loop and i got the console error just like this

> flow:finish_connect 2016-11-08 11:55:02.424070 OPT JOBS[2410:49655] []
>   nw_connection_endpoint_report [16 graph.facebook.com:443 ready
>   resolver (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_connect 2016-11-08
>   11:55:02.424919 OPT JOBS[2410:49661] []
>   __tcp_connection_start_block_invoke 16 sending event TCP_CONNECTION_EVENT_TLS_HANDSHAKE_COMPLETE in response to state ready
>   and error (null) 2016-11-08 11:55:02.425626 OPT JOBS[2410:49661] []
>   tcp_connection_event_notify 16 event:
>   TCP_CONNECTION_EVENT_TLS_HANDSHAKE_COMPLETE, reason: nw_connection
>   event, should deliver: true 2016-11-08 11:55:02.426673 OPT
>   JOBS[2410:49661] [] tcp_connection_get_statistics DNS: 18ms/24ms since
>   start, TCP: 100ms/135ms since start, TLS: 211ms/343ms since start
>   2016-11-08 11:55:02.445829 OPT JOBS[2410:49655] []
>   nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_connected [17.1 31.13.78.13:443 in_progress
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] Output protocol connected 2016-11-08
>   11:55:02.447545 OPT JOBS[2410:49655] []
>   nw_endpoint_flow_connected_path_change [17.1 31.13.78.13:443 ready
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] 2016-11-08 11:55:02.448063 OPT
>   JOBS[2410:49655] [] nw_endpoint_flow_connected_path_change [17.1
>   31.13.78.13:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Connected path is satisfied 2016-11-08 11:55:02.448526 OPT JOBS[2410:49655] []
>   nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [17 graph.facebook.com:443
>   in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[17.1
>   31.13.78.13:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] 2016-11-08 11:55:02.448948 OPT JOBS[2410:49655] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report
>   [17.1 31.13.78.13:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event
>   flow:finish_connect 2016-11-08 11:55:02.449428 OPT JOBS[2410:49655] []
>   nw_connection_endpoint_report [17 graph.facebook.com:443 ready
>   resolver (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_connect 2016-11-08
>   11:55:02.449908 OPT JOBS[2410:49558] []
>   __tcp_connection_start_block_invoke 17 sending event TCP_CONNECTION_EVENT_TLS_HANDSHAKE_COMPLETE in response to state ready
>   and error (null) 2016-11-08 11:55:02.544663 OPT JOBS[2410:49558] []
>   tcp_connection_event_notify 17 event:
>   TCP_CONNECTION_EVENT_TLS_HANDSHAKE_COMPLETE, reason: nw_connection
>   event, should deliver: true 2016-11-08 11:55:02.545103 OPT
>   JOBS[2410:49558] [] tcp_connection_get_statistics DNS: 11ms/18ms since
>   start, TCP: 112ms/146ms since start, TLS: 220ms/362ms since start
>   2016-11-08 11:55:02.747101 OPT JOBS[2410:49551] []
>   nw_socket_handle_socket_event Event mask: 0x4 2016-11-08
>   11:55:02.747501 OPT JOBS[2410:49662] [] tcp_connection_cancel 16
>   2016-11-08 11:55:02.747984 OPT JOBS[2410:49551] []
>   nw_socket_handle_socket_event Socket received WRITE_CLOSE event
>   2016-11-08 11:55:02.748361 OPT JOBS[2410:49551] []
>   nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [16 graph.facebook.com:443 ready resolver
>   (satisfied)] 2016-11-08 11:55:02.748705 OPT JOBS[2410:49551] []
>   nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [16.1 31.13.78.13:443 ready socket-flow
>   (satisfied)] 2016-11-08 11:55:02.749132 OPT JOBS[2410:49551] []
>   __nw_socket_service_writes_block_invoke sendmsg(fd 9, 31 bytes): socket has been closed 2016-11-08 11:55:02.749475 OPT JOBS[2410:49551]
>   [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_error [16.1 31.13.78.13:443 cancelled
>   socket-flow (null)] Socket protocol sent error: [32] Broken pipe
>   2016-11-08 11:55:02.749751 OPT JOBS[2410:49551] []
>   nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_disconnected [16.1 31.13.78.13:443 cancelled
>   socket-flow (null)] Output protocol disconnected 2016-11-08
>   11:55:02.750124 OPT JOBS[2410:49551] [] nw_resolver_cancel_on_queue
>   0x7a086580 2016-11-08 11:55:02.750463 OPT JOBS[2410:49551] []
>   -[NWConcrete_tcp_connection dealloc] 16 2016-11-08 11:55:02.867926 OPT JOBS[2410:49661] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event Event mask: 0x4
>   2016-11-08 11:55:02.868244 OPT JOBS[2410:49558] []
>   tcp_connection_cancel 17 2016-11-08 11:55:02.868817 OPT
>   JOBS[2410:49661] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event Socket received
>   WRITE_CLOSE event 2016-11-08 11:55:02.869206 OPT JOBS[2410:49661] []
>   nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [17 graph.facebook.com:443 ready resolver
>   (satisfied)] 2016-11-08 11:55:02.869432 OPT JOBS[2410:49661] []
>   nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [17.1 31.13.78.13:443 ready socket-flow
>   (satisfied)] 2016-11-08 11:55:02.869919 OPT JOBS[2410:49661] []
>   __nw_socket_service_writes_block_invoke sendmsg(fd 10, 31 bytes): socket has been closed 2016-11-08 11:55:02.870149 OPT JOBS[2410:49661]
>   [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_error [17.1 31.13.78.13:443 cancelled
>   socket-flow (null)] Socket protocol sent error: [32] Broken pipe
>   2016-11-08 11:55:02.870549 OPT JOBS[2410:49661] []
>   nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_disconnected [17.1 31.13.78.13:443 cancelled
>   socket-flow (null)] Output protocol disconnected 2016-11-08
>   11:55:02.870896 OPT JOBS[2410:49661] [] nw_resolver_cancel_on_queue
>   0x7a08e1b0 2016-11-08 11:55:02.871251 OPT JOBS[2410:49661] []
>   -[NWConcrete_tcp_connection dealloc] 17

**so can anyone help me to find out the Solution for ios10 and xcode 8**

Answer (score 0):

```
                **In Capabilities tab Keychain Sharing should be enable.**
                **Also Make sure you have added this to your plist**

                 <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
                    <array>
                        <dict>
                            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                            <array>
                                <string>fb648725325301980</string>
                            </array>
                        </dict>
                    </array>
                    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
                    <string>648725325301980</string>
                    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
                    <string>MeetBox</string>
                    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>fbapi</string>
                        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
                        <string>fbauth2</string>
                        <string>fbshareextension</string>
                    </array>



             - **If it is still not working then replace your code with this**

                **Swift**

                -(IBAction)ClickFacebook:(id)sender
                {
                        let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
                        loginManager.logOut()
                        loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_likes", "user_relationship_details", "user_relationships"], from: self, handler: {(result , error) -> Void in
                            print("Value of Result is \(result)")
                            print("Value of Error is \(error)")
                            if (error != nil) {
                                let cont = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Something Went Wrong", preferredStyle: .alert)
                                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                                })
                                cont.addAction(okAction)
                                self.present(cont, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
                            }
                            else if (result?.isCancelled)!
                            {

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil)
                                {
                                    let homeVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController")
                                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeVC!, animated: true)
                                    FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil).start(completionHandler: {(connection, result, error) -> Void in

                                        print("Value of Error is", error)
                                        print("Value of Result is", result)

                                        if error == nil
                                        {
                                            FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"picture.width(500).height(500),first_name,email,last_name,location,gender,likes,interested_in,friends"]).start(completionHandler: {(connection, result, error) -> Void in

                                                print("ResultArray: ",result)
                                            })
                                        }
                                    })
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }

         **Objective C**

   -(IBAction)ClickFacebook:(id)sender
             {
            FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc]init];
            [loginManager logOut];

            [loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email",@"user_friends",@"user_likes",@"user_relationship_details"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult result, NSError error) {

                NSLog(@"Value of Result is %@",result);
                NSLog(@"Value of Error is %@",error);

                if (error)
                {
                    UIAlertController *cont = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Something Went Wrong" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                    UIAlertAction okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction    _Nonnull action) {

                    }];

                    [cont addAction:okAction];
                    [self presentViewController:cont animated:true completion:nil];
                }
                else if (result.isCancelled)
                {

                    //Permission Canceled

                }
                else
                {
                    //User Accept Permission

                    NSLog(@"Granded Permissions are %@",result.grantedPermissions);

                    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
                    {

                        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection connection, id result, NSError error) {

                            NSLog(@"Value of Error is %@",error);
                            NSLog(@"Value of Result is %@",result);


                            if (error == nil)
                            {

                                //
                                [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"picture.width(500).height(500),first_name,email,last_name,location,gender,likes,interested_in"}]startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection connection, id result, NSError error) {

                                    NSLog(@"Value of Result is %@",result);
                                    NSLog(@"Value of Error is %@",error);

                                    if ( error != nil)
                                    {

                                        // NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

                                       // myPagesArray = [[result valueForKey:@"likes"]valueForKey:@"data"];

                                    }
                                }];

                            }
                            else
                            {

                                //Something Went Wrong...
                            }

                        }];
                    }
                }
            }];
        }


    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

        [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];

        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }
```

Comment: this config i have already done bcs of that reason that was working in ios9

Comment: Try this code I have cut this from iOS 10. Think it should work in iOS 10

Comment: Oh you are working in objective C. Ok let me do that.

Answer (score 0):

In My app also Facebook and Google Login not working in iOS 10. So I have made ON keychain sharing and it works.

check this  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39568942/3901620